# $_POST empty after fetch formData

Tags: javascript, php, post, fetch

when I try to fetch a formData with POST from JS to PHP, I obtain an empty $_POST array(), despite of Status Code is 200 OK. Can you help me?

```
function select_collection()
 {
  const tendina=document.querySelectorAll(".tendina");
   for(all of tendina)
        {
           all.addEventListener('change', aggiungi);
        }
    }
    function aggiungi(event){
        const tendina=event.target;
        const val=tendina.options[tendina.selectedIndex].value; 

        const row_box= tendina.parentNode.parentNode; 
        const child=row_box.childNodes;

            const url_image=child[0].childNodes[0].currentSrc;

            const id_google=child[1].childNodes[0].textContent.slice(11,);
            const titolo= child[1].childNodes[1].textContent.slice(8,);
            const autore= child[1].childNodes[2].textContent.slice(8,);
            const editore=child[1].childNodes[3].textContent.slice(9,);
            const pagine=child[1].childNodes[4].textContent.slice(8,);
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('titolo_racc', val);
            formData.append('id_google', id_google);
            formData.append('titolo', titolo);
            formData.append('autore', autore);
            formData.append('editore', editore);
            formData.append('pagine', pagine);
            fetch('http://localhost/progetto/inserisci_contenuto.php',{
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
          }).then(onResponse).then(onText);
```

.tendina it's the class of a drop-down menù (select, option), title, author, publisher and pages refers to a book volume infos.
I want to send this info to a PHP page.

```
$conn=new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die ("Connection failed " .$conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST["titolo_racc"]) && isset($_POST["id_google"] && isset($_POST["titolo"] && isset($_POST["autore"] && isset($_POST["editore"] && isset($_POST["pagine"]))
{
    print_r($_POST); // array ()
    print_r($_POST["titolo"]; //Undefined index:
}
```

Comment: The content type shouldn't be `application/json`, it should be `multipart/form-data`. You don't need to specify that yourself, it will be done automatically by `fetch()` when the body is `FormData`.

Comment: did you check your console?

Comment: FYI, `tendina.options[tendina.selectedIndex].value` can be simplified to just `tendina.value`.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of:

```
    headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json;"}),
```

it's incorrect, since you're sending `multipart/form-data` format. You need to allow `fetch()` to provide this header by itself, since it needs to include the separator string, which is generated randomly internally.

Comment: Thanks, I've yet tried to delete headers, but the situation remain the same.

Comment: Try `method: "POST"` I think it may be case-sensitive.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't change, it shows always GET. Apart from this, in the Console-->Network, I see 

equest URL: http://localhost/progetto/inserisci_contenuto.php
**Request Method: POST**
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Where are you calling the fetch code from? I suspect you're sending two requests, one from fetch, and another from a link or form, and you're seeing the results of the latter.

Comment: I call the fetch from a function called by ad EventListener on a click on a select-option menù.

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else that goes to the same URL? I don't think the request you're seeing is coming from that function.

Comment: I create the url file related, only when I write the fetch. First of this I never call this file "inserisci_contenuto.php".
I have a session_start() to transmit cookie, but I used it in all the other php file. I also use the POST method in LOGIN.php page, and I copy the code that in the LOGIN page works weel, but here no. I don't know why

Comment: Console->Network says you're sending POST, but PHP says it received GET? I can't explain that.

Comment: Do you see the parameters if you do `print_r($_GET)`?

Comment: No, it shows only Array ( )   also with print_r($_GET)

Comment: I'm not sure if it would cause this kind of problem, but could there be a redirect configured on the server?

Comment: No, I use XAMPP, but I repeat that in other page of the project, like login page, I used POST method and also GET with lots of fetch and they all work very well

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain it. The `fetch()` code is correct, the problem is happening somewhere else.

Comment: Is it possible a problem of refreshing php page? Or preventing default of the event ?

Comment: I don't think so. Refreshing the page shouldn't send a GET request to this URL, unless it's the same URL as the page uses. And the default action of a `<select>` doesn't send a GET request.

Comment: I used 'change on the eventListener, not submit

Comment: Of course, since a `<select>` doesn't get a submit event, that only happens to forms.

Comment: I suggest you set a debugger breakpoint in the code, and see where it's being called from.

Comment: This code may be hitting the case where, if the browser receives a 301 or 301 response to the POST, the browser changes the request method to GET — that is, the browser makes the request to the redirect URL as a GET request rather than a POST.

Comment: But why when I use print_r($_GET) it prints always Array() ?

Comment: Because whatever is sending the GET request isn't sending any parameters.

Comment: The case I mentioned in my earlier comment is required by the Fetch spec; see step #11 at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-redirect-fetch

Comment: @sideshowbarker That's correct. Normally the redirect is sent *after* processing the POST request, not before.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the problem is in the session_start(), that I use to recognize the user_id. In fact, if I try to use $_SESSION["user"], i don't know why, it doesn't work.

If I don't write the session_start(), all the print_r and echo work very well, also with the fetched values.

The strange thing is that I use the session method in every others php pages of my website.